# Application is not deploying on device

Tags: android, android-studio

Previously i used to run apps on my device but from yesterday unfortunately i am unable to run application on device. When i run application on android studio device chooser dialog pops up and shows my connected device.But if i click OK then do nothing, even not showing any error on logcat. If i open a debuggable app on my handset logcat shows logging as usual. I can't find out why app is not deploying on device.

I have also tried following :

- Creating new project.
- Making developer options and usb debugging off and again on.
- Restarting android studio and handset.
- Adding in build.gradle file

  ```
  buildTypes {
     debug {
      debuggable true
     }
  }
  ```

Comment: what was errors in **`Run window`** ?

Comment: nothing happens... no errors are shown.

Comment: Nobody is replying and also voting negative without any reason. I have downloaded newer version and problem solved. But i am confused  why should i do that.

Comment: We can not say what was problem, but some time adb commands not execute by Android studio. I face the same but after restart i works for me. Also i got errors in run windows. Any how now its workings right ! Cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because i am using '+' sign in gradle.

So, change :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
```

to specific one:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'
```